# SSRS - AccessDeniedException when running reports via Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I recently cloned an SSRS native installation from one set of application and db servers to another. The keys from the old installation were backed up and successfully re-applied in the new installation restoring access to all encrypted data.

Existing users were able to access and run reports under the new installation using the SSRS web portal; however, *some* of these users were not able to run the same reports via the Report Builder that was connected this new installation.

The error they got, for example, was the following: `Microsoft Report Builder: Failed to preview report. The permissions granted to user 'mydomain\abc' are insufficient for performing this operation. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException: The permissions granted to user 'mydomain\abc' are insufficient for performing this operation"`

The user 'mydomain\abc' in the above example already has the roles "`Content Manager`" and "`Report Builder`" assigned to him at the root, folder and report level.

The same report under the old installation when opened via the report builder worked for this user.

With regards to permissions, the old and new installation are identical.

**Environment info:**

```
SSRS 2016 Native deployment
OS: Windows 2016 Server
DB: SQL Server Enterprise Edition 2016
```

Could I request assistance with fixing this problem?

Comment: Are the old and new SSRS servers in the same domain? Are the problem logins also in that same domain, or are they instead local logins (machine\username)? The ReportServer's `Users` table records a binary SID for Windows authenticated users so if these were local accounts they will need to be recreated on the new server and then the corresponding binary SIDs updated to match.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Yes, the old and new SSRS servers are in the same domain. And the user mentioned here is an active directory user in the same domain.

Answer (score 2):

The "Report Builder" role provides the ability to "view report definitions".  However, at the server level (under Site Settings) there is a "System User" role which, among other things, allows for "use of Report Builder or other clients that execute report definitions".  Are the users with the problem in this site-level role?  Anyway, we had the same problem and adding the user to the "System User" role solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved this issue: Remote into SSRS server. Open Report Server Configuration Manager. Select Web Portal URL. Click the reports url link. Provide admin credentials to login to the link if needed. In the SQL Server Reporting Services website, click Settings and select Site settings. Choose Security tab. Click Add group or user. Enter the Group or User in the textbox and choose System User role and click OK.